# How to read from a file without a gap?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have read/printed out 2 lines from a file but there is a gap in between them but I want to but both of them beside each other , how do I do that.

```
if GTIN == '86947367':
    fp = open("read_it.txt")
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 1:
            print(line)
        elif i == 2:
            print(line)
    fp.close()
```

When I run this it gives an output of:

```
banana
(space)
(space)
5.00
```

I wanna put  both `print(line)`besides each other to give an output of:

```
banana 5.00
```

TEXT FILE:

```
86947367
banana
5.00

78364721
apple
3.00

35619833
orange
2.00

84716491
sweets
8.00

46389121
chicken
10.00

74937462
```

Comment: Please tell something about the structure of the file. Do you need to read other lines? Please provide some examples.

Comment: I just need to read two specific lines , lines 1 and 2 and print them out.the file structured that each word has its own line so e.g banana is on one line then under it is 5.00.

Comment: Please show the input text file.

Comment: I  added the text file

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
    next(fp)
    print(next(fp).rstrip(), next(fp))
```

prints:

```
banana 5.00
```

First you open the file with promise to close it `with open("read_it.txt") as fp:'`. Now you use `next(fp)` to skip the first line. Finally, you print the content of both lines. You need to strip the newline character at the end of the first printed line with `.rstrip()`.

Your file object `fp` is a so called iterator. That means `next(fp)` gives you the next line.

This would work, if you want to print the output for your `GTIN`:

```
with open("read_it.txt") as fp:
    GTIN = '86947367'
    show = False
    for line in fp:
        if not line.strip():
            show = False
            continue
        if line.strip() == GTIN:
            show = True
            continue
        if show:
            print(line.rstrip(), end=' ')
```

prints:

```
banana 5.00
```

Comment: what does the function .strip do please ? Can you explain your code , I am a noobie.

Comment: It strips the newline character at the end of the line. This is part of the line when your read from the file.

Comment: thanks so what if I wanted to print out lines 4 and 5 what do I change in the code.And beside `banana 5.00` I want to print a variable called quantity but I tried  `and print(quantity)` which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("read_it.txt") as f: print(' '.join([f.readline().rstrip() for x in range(3)][1:]))
```

Comment: firstly can you explain what you just did please , I am kind of baffled and secondly do I add this before I close the file ?

Comment: in python3.x you have a beautiful `with` statement which closes the file automatically. All three versions do the following: open file, read two lines,  remove last char (which is newline character), print the result joined and close the file

Comment: So the first code you gave me works , thanks , but what do I change in it for other lines for example lines 5 and 6.Sorry but I am new to files in python and I would really appreciate an explanation for a learner.And this is for school so I can't just copy and paste any code without knowing what it means.

Comment: I hope you don't re-read the file again and again? I mean, it's preferrable to read the file only once and after that do everything you need with the collected data. What is the task? Could you please add some information into the question about the goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So if the user enters the code e.g.8523523 then it will look for the two lines under the code in the text file (if you download the text file you will see a code with a product name under it and a price under that).it will need to print out the code , the name of the product and the price next to each other.